# How do I update NetSuite Department isInactive via WSDL?

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to update NetSuite Department via WSDL but I'm having an issue updating isInactive. Below is my code in C#:

```
var record = new com.netsuite.webservices.Department
{
 internalId = dp.InternalId,
 isInactive = dp.InActive
};
```

then called

```
var result = ServiceClient.update(record);
```

The Department's DEPARTMENT IS INACTIVE on NetSuite doesn't check whether I set it to true or false. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to set `isInactiveSpecified`

Try this:

```
var record = new com.netsuite.webservices.Department
{
 internalId = dp.InternalId,
 isInactive = dp.InActive,
 isInactiveSpecified = true
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first `.get()` the record, set some properties, then `.update()` the record.  Here's what works for me:

```cs
var ns = new NetSuite.NetSuiteService();
// passport info skipped

var departmentRef = new RecordRef
{
    internalId = "1",
    type = RecordType.department,
    typeSpecified = true
};

var response = ns.get(departmentRef);
var department = response.record as Department;
department.isInactive = true;
ns.update(department);
```